# Server-side Websocket implementations in non-event driven HTTP Server Environments

Tags: perl, websocket, psgi

I am trying to understand implementations/options for server-side Websocket endpoints - particularly in Perl using PSGI/Plack and I have a question: Why are all server-side websocket implementations based around event-driven PSGI servers (Twiggy, Tatsumaki, etc.)?

I get that websocket communication is asynchronous, but a non-event driven PSGI server (say Starman) could spawn an asynchronous listener to handle the websocket side of things. I have seen (but not understood) PHP implementations of Websocket servers, so why cant the same be done with PSGI without having to change the server to an event driven one?

Comment: Websockets typically involve long-running connections. With a pre-fork server, you'll quickly run out of memory on your server.

Comment: First hit for [php websockets](http://socketo.me/docs/deploy) involves a separate async process.

Answer (score 1):

Underlying network logic to deal with sockets depends on platform, OS and particular software implementations.
Most common three methods are:

- **pulling** - there is blocking constant "asking" if socket has some data. This method is well bad, as it will block execution of main thread for as long as it waits for some data.
- **thread per socket** - each new connection involves creating new thread and asking each socket in blocking manner happens within that thread. So it wont block main thread with logic. This method is bad as creating thread for each connection is too expensive for memory, and can be around 1Mb or RAM based on OS and other criteria.
- **async** - uses system features to "notify" your process when there is something. So you can react once your app is ready (in case of single threaded app) or even react in separate thread straight away. This method is well efficient as it saves RAM, and allows your app to work without need of waiting or asking for data. It utilises existing functionalities that most OS and platforms provide.

Taking this in account, you indeed can create single process functional way to deal with sockets traffic. But that is not efficient at all as been proven previously. That is why fully async models are major today, as most languages and platforms do support such paradigm.